# HTML Razor DropDowListFor returns null if checkbox for is unchecked

Tags: c#, html, razor

I have a user creation form which has stopped working and is erroring out with a null value for the supervisor drop down list when the Is_Supervisor check box is unchecked, but works perfectly when it is checked.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
@model WebLeaveRequest1.Models.AddUserModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddUser", "LeaveRequest"))
{
   <div class="form-group">
        <label for=Supervisor>Supervisor:</label>
       @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Supervisor, new SelectList(ViewBag.sup_list, "Text", "Value"), "")
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for=Is_Supervisor> Is Supervisor:</label>
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Is_Supervisor)
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Register" />
}
```

Here is my controller and the code that is filling the dropdown:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AddUser()
{
    Make_Sup();
    Make_Role();
    Make_Mentor();
    return View();
}

public void Make_Sup()
{
    var query = from entry in db.tbl_user
                where entry.is_supervisor.ToString() == "True"
                select new
                {
                    name = entry.first_name +" "+ entry.last_name,
                    userid = entry.userid
                };
    ViewBag.sup_list = new SelectList(query, "name", "userid");
}
```

Additionally here is an almost identical HTML page for the same website that works flawlessly:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
@model WebLeaveRequest1.Models.AddUserModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("EditUser_Edit", "LeaveRequest"))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Userid">Userid: </label>
        @ViewBag.Userid
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for=Supervisor>Supervisor: </label>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Supervisor, new SelectList(ViewBag.sup_list, "Text", "Value"), new { @Value = ViewBag.Supervisor })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for=Is_Supervisor> Is Supervisor: </label>
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Is_Supervisor, new { @Value = ViewBag.Is_Supervisor })
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Update" />
}
```

AddUserModel

```html
 public class AddUserModel
    {
        public string Userid { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Password1 { get; set; }
        public string First_Name { get; set; }
        public string Last_Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public bool Is_Supervisor { get; set; }
        public string Supervisor { get; set; }
        public string Supervisor_Level { get; set; }
        public string Mentor { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: unrelated, but you should put try-catch blocks in for temp data. you should check for null instead. i usually do something like this `bool myVal = (bool?)TempData["myVal"] ?? false;`

Comment: you have posted a lot of code, can you pare it down to the parts that are relevant to your problem?

Comment: I parsed down the html to the problem parts, and removed the post code since it was not making it to that point.

Comment: can you post the definition of your model? Also, you shouldn't be using the ViewBag like this, because it's easy to have the types be incorrect, causing a mismatch in the dropdown options and the available supervisors. you should instead make a model property that is `IEnumerable<Supervisor>` or something and use that as the source for your dropdown options.

Comment: also, you should form your html properly, put quotes in your `<label for=Supervisor>` etc

Comment: `ViewBag.sup_list` doesn't have properties named "Text" and "Value"

Comment: My understanding is that "Text" and "Value" are for the SelectList,  I've also added the model

Answer (score 0):

Your `SelectList` isn't being created properly. The names of the properties in `ViewBag.sup_list` aren't "Text" and "Value", they're `name` and `userid`. This should fix the problem:

```
new SelectList(ViewBag.sup_list, "name", "userid")
```

Comment: When I pass `"name"` and `"userid"` it errors on page load saying that the select list does not have the property `name`

Comment: are you sure `ViewBag.sup_list` isn't being set somewhere else? this is another reason you shouldn't use the `ViewBag` like this

Comment: Yes, `ViewBag.sup_list` is created in the get call right before the view is displayed, additionally if the check box is checked the code works without a problem

Comment: I also tried passing a model with an `IEnumerable<Supervisor>` rather than using the View Bag, however I get an error saying that: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.  When the check box after is set however the code again works correctly.

Comment: I found the problem, in my post code I had an if statement that would find a logical problem and was supposed to return the page with a message, however I had failed to reinitialize the dropdown boxes so when the view was called the error  struck. Thanks for your help.